# Linking figure caption number to chapter number in a different style than Heading 1 in Word

Tags: ms-word, figure, caption, multi-level

I am using a customized thesis template where the styles are manually created. However, there are no standard Word styles, such as "Heading X." I am trying to include chapter numbers in my figure captions. While attempting to do so, I've selected `include chapter number` in the `Caption Numbering` settings. Unfortunately, I encountered an issue; the `Chapter starts with style` cell only displays standard Word styles (Heading 1-9). It doesn't show styles other than Heading X. Consequently, I am unable to add chapter numbers in front of my figure numbers with my Chapter style (let's say "Title1") within the captions. Can anyone provide guidance on how to accomplish this?

[image]

I checked the multilevel list in the Home tab and looked through modifying the style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open the `Caption Numbering` window, you cannot access any style other than Windows' own standard styles (Heading X) under `Chapter starts with style`. I was able to find a solution as follows:
After writing a title with the style I created and wanted to use, I opened the `Styles` window with this style selected as the style type. Here, when I clicked on the downward arrow next to `Heading 1`, then I selected `Update Heading 1 to Match Selection` from the menu that opened. So, I copied the content of the style I created to Heading 1. In this case, if you select Heading 1 when you want to add the Chapter number, it links figure caption number to related chapter number successfully.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the "Caption Numbering" window, check the "Include chapter number" checkbox and select any of the styles that are available. Complete the rest of the caption as you want in the parent window (`Caption`), and click OK to insert the caption.

In the caption that was just inserted, right click on the first field (the one that should be corresponding to your chapter), and select "Edit field...". Under "Field properties," there is the list, "Style name," that should include all styles in your document. Select the style you want to use for the chapter number in your caption.

Unfortunately, you do have to do this manually for each caption. So if you have a lot of tables/figures to which this applies, Salim's suggestion is probably more practical.